# What is the use of a right-module?

Tags: group-theory, modules, representation-theory

It seems that only the left-module provides a representation of a group. So what is the use of a right-module?

Comment: Sometimes there are constructions which are naturally both left and right modules ("bimodules"), for example. An important example in representation theory is the group algebra $k[G]$ itself, which is naturally a $k[G]$-bimodule.

Comment: You can choose for yourself whether you use right or left modules in representation theory. Personally I prefer right modules. (They correspond to right actions, composing permutations from left to right, etc)